# How can I solve this issue The page is not working HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, mysql, http, prepared-statement

How can I solve this problem?
I am trying to fetch records from the database using the prepared statement. This is working on localhost but not on online hosting.

db.php

```
<?php
class Db {
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "guru77";
private $pwd  = "123456";
private $dbName = "testingProjects";

protected function connect(){
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbName;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$this->user,$this->pwd);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
}
```

}

post_view.php

```
<?php

class Post_view extends Post{

public function show(){
    $results = $this->showAll();
    return $results;
}
```

}

?>

post.php

```
<?php
class Post extends Db{


protected function  showAll(){
        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM posts";
        $stmt   = $this->connect()->query($sql);            
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $results;
    }
```

}

?>

index.php

```
<?php
  require_once('db.php');
  require_once('post_view.php');
  require_once('post.php');

$obj = new Post_view();
  $rows = $obj->show();

    ?>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php foreach($rows as $row){

        echo $row['title'];

        }?>
    </body>
</html>
```

output - 
[image]

Comment: Your hosting provider may have different `mysql` hostname. Make suer you use the right name to connect to mysql server.

Comment: You are not using prepared statements. You should check your server's error log.

Comment: Also you have to check your `Connection` before you do any queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 500 Internal Server Error is the general catch all error when the server throws an exception. Simply, the 500 Internal Server Error is a general *http* status code that means something has gone wrong on the website's server.

Please check the followings,
check if your online hosting service, database credentials are same.(values on below variables.). hose may be different in online host than your localhost.

```
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "guru77";
private $pwd  = "123456";
private $dbName = "testingProjects";
```

alternatively, you can check your database connection by simply running this,

```
<?php

$hostname= "localhost";
$db= "database";
$user= "user";
$pass= "password";

$checkConn= new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $db);
// Check connection
if ($checkConn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $checkConn->connect_error);
}
  echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

it'd be more helpful, if you can get the server's error log data, which will be helpful on debugging

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. I did not include the post.php file in post_view.php. I checked in error_log

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

You have an missing semicolon in your DNS record:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbName;
```

Should be like this:

```
$dsn = '"mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbName . '"';
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can Use

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql: host=localhost; dbname12', 'myusername', 'password');
```

Comment: What are you improving with this?